# Why do I need to change floating point numbers to integers?

Tags: python, theory

I have a theoretical question. Why do we need integers in Python if we can always use floating point numbers? For memory saving? I wonder if there are more reasons.

Comment: https://0.30000000000000004.com/ ... floating point numbers are not guaranteed to be exact. Floating point math is slower than integer math.

Comment: Not only are they not exact, as @blackbrandt, points out, floating-point arithmetic is also neither associative nor distributive (generally).

Comment: `Integer`s in python are unbounded. This means there is no minimum to maximum limits (except your hardware). `Float`s don't provide such freedom.

Comment: One can certainly make interpreters with only floating point numbers (JS, Basic). Performance considerations aside, ints are just plain convenient, have well established semantics and are robust. Many common operations such as bit fields can only be expressed in float by converting to int. Also, keep in mind that Python was designed as a teaching and prototyping language. You want to teach integer math because most other languages have it.